# Amazon Lambda inbound-ses-spam-filter (python)

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I want to do some simple filtering with a lambda script that will drop emails based on spamVerdict, virusVerdict, etc.  There is a nodejs blueprint that already has most of the functionality I want, but I don't want to use nodejs.  Checking the python documentation of the context object seems to indicate that there is no "succeed" method for me to stop processing the SES ruleset.  Further, simply calling: `context.succeed({ "disposition" : "STOP_RULE_SET" });` gives the error:

```
"errorType": "AttributeError",
"errorMessage": "'LambdaContext' object has no attribute 'succeed'"
```

I thought Python was a "first class citizen"?  How do I stop processing the ruleset ?

Answer (score 3):

[Mark B is correct](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35371576); Python doesn't call back to the context object the way NodeJS does. Rather, it uses the return of the handler function instead. There's example code in the script I linked below, but for reference, stopping the rule set looks like this:

```
    return {'disposition': 'stop_rule_set'}
```

There's a Python blueprint in the works, but for now I've posted a Pythonized version of the NodeJS blueprint here:

https://github.com/dldorsey/python-ses/blob/master/lambda_function.py

Answer (score 2):

I imagine that the `context.succeed()` and similar methods were added to the NodeJS version of Lambda due to the asynchronous nature of NodeJS programming.

For Python Lambda functions it appears you simply need to `return`